# how to run linux command in magento1

Tags: magento-1.9, command, linux

How to run below linux command in Magento 1 under observer/model?

```
grep -n 'tracker' test.txt
```

which can be later used for cron?

Comment: What exactly, you trying to achieve?

Comment: want to read apache log incrementally for some matching pattern then want o/p to send to one mail id.

And it'll run by cron.